# Passing immigration when father and child hold a different passports

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, children

I am the father of an infant child who currently has a different nationality to me (I hold an EU passport, and he has a non-EU passport).

On both of our passports we share the same surname.

My question is: What problems can I anticipate traveling with my child and without their mom?

Would immigration staff in any parts of the world deny us entry based on having different nationality passports?

This is a [near duplicate of this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/child-travelling-with-different-nationality-passport-than-mom), that suggests traveling with the birth certificate as well. However as a father I am concerned that I may face more issues than a mother in the same situation?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: If possible a signed letter from the mother authorising the intended travel might help.

Comment: Question exactly: "Would immigration staff in any parts of the world deny us entry based on having different nationality passports?"

Comment: @Andrew then it's a direct duplicate of the other question?

Comment: If you think a father would have more problems than a mother, then follow the advice given in the other question. A letter from the other parent and a birth certificate should cover you. These letters are a good idea even when everyone has the same passport.

Comment: @Andrew Depending on what passport the infant holds and what country you're traveling to you may have a problem leaving more then entering the country.

Comment: Mightn't an additional problem be that parent and child have to stand in different queues?

Comment: You wouldn't have to stand in different queues. You can go through the non-EU queue with an EU passport if you want to and in this case that would make sense. Or they will likely be more than happy to let the kid go through the EU queue since they are with you anyway. I've got an EU passport and my kids have Australian ones and we've always gone through the queues together. Always also with their mum though.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am thinking that the question is just too broad since it depends on policy of the origin and destination countries (both immigration and emigration on both sides) as well as the passports in question.

Comment: @uncovery As stated in the question, I believe that traveling with a father may be sufficiently different to not be considered duplicate.

Comment: Although the question is different, the rules are exactly the same as to the "mother" question.

Comment: @gerrit There is usually no “non-EU queue”, only an “all passports queue”. The “EU queue” is convenient because it's faster but that's all.